# Difference between ldrsh, ldrh, strh, and strsh

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm not sure when to use ldrsh vs ldrsh and strh vs strsh

I know that one is for unsigned and another is for signed, but how do we know when we need to save it signed or unsigned?

For example,

```
short a[5];
short *ptr;

*(a+3) = a[1];
ldrsh    r3, [fp, -12]
strh     r3, [fp, -8]
```

This is a snippet of ARM assembly code from my worksheet. I just don't see why we ysed ldrsh for one instruction and strh for another.

Comment: Because one is a load and the other is a store? Could have used `ldrh` for the load too if all you want to do is store it. `strsh` doesn't exist.

Comment: The above assembly code effectively does `int r3 = a[1]; a[3] = r3;` Using `ldrh` would more closely match the C version.

Comment: @fuz: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABDJFDA.html `SH
for Signed Halfword (LDR only)`.  Jester is right, `strsh` isn't an ARM instruction.  There's nothing to sign-extend; instead you're truncating a 32-bit register to 16 bits.  (This just grabs the low bits, not signed saturation or anything weird, so a stored doesn't care if the upper bits are zero or sign-extended or some arbitrary value).

Comment: @Jester I would have thought that `ldrsh` most closely matches the C version as `short` is signed..  If the types in C were `unsigned short` then, yes, `ldrh` would be used.

Answer (score 6):

The `ldrsh` instruction loads a half-word i.e. 16 bits (the `h` in `ldrsh`) and sign-extends (the `s` in `ldrsh`) it to the 32-bits of the register.
The `ldrh` instruction would zero-extend the loaded 16-bits to 32-bits.
The reason you get the sign-extending behaviour is because the `short` type is a signed type.

To store a half-word you would always use the `strh` instruction that just takes the bottom 16 bits of the register and stores them. There is no `strsh` instruction as there is no sign-specific processing needed to just take the bottom 16 bits.

Since your code loads a 16-bit value and immediately stores it as a 16-bit value the `ldrh` instruction would have done the job as well. In this case it doesn't matter. But if you wanted to do any arithmetic on the value in between, you definitely want the `ldrsh` to do the proper sign-extension.